# AD Reset Multiple Passwords Simultaneously from LDAP Query

Tags: active-directory, user-management

I have used a custom query in Active Directory to identify all users that have never logged in to the the domain. I need to reset all of their passwords and as there are several hundred I would prefer to do this as one bulk task. Although I know many would argue (reasonably) against it, it's entirely fine for me to use the same password for every user.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jonny

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it fail? What part of the failure was unexpected? You've also failed to ask an actual question. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I have used the AD U&C utility, I was able to run my search query and manually select the user accounts I need but bulk password reset does not seem to be possible with this utility or if it is the process is different to the password reset for an individual user. In terms of what help I need it's to know what the process is for performing a batch reset on a number of users simultaneously, ideally through AD U&C or if not then a description of how that is typically achieved.

Comment: Some further searching suggests that I can create a group for my selected users and then use a powershell script to edit that group as a whole but what I've seen isn't clear and I would hope that there is an easier and more efficient way to manage this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to using something other than ADUC, you can use PowerShell:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | where {$_.LastLogonDate -eq $null} | Set-ADAccountPassword
```

Comment: Liam, slightly nervous about potentially ruining something as I don't know PowerShell well but I suspect I will have to take the risk at some stage and this is exactly the sort of thing I was talking about so thank you very much :D

Comment: PowerShell is VERY use friendly. When it comes to using it for administration, you'll typically see a `Get | Set` pair. If you're worried about hitting the wrong accounts, just run the `Get`. If you see the accounts you'd expect to see, add the `Set` and you're golden. If you're worried that the `Set` isn't what you want, run it against a single account: `Set-ADAccountPassword JDoe`.